# Navigation Links for CMS Pages

Tags: magento2, navigation, toplinks

I've been trying to figure out how to add links to the top navigation for **Magento 2**.

In 1.x we'd just URL rewrites, however, that doesn't seem to work in Magento 2.x at this point. I added a new category Home. Then, I went to: `Marketing > URL Rewrites`, and edited the URL rewrite (changing the Redirect Type to 301) and saved it. Next, I clicked Add URL Rewrite, type Custom and used request path of "`catalog/category/view/id/23`" and target path /. I tried the redirect type as none and 301.

Is this done differently in Magento 2? Or is there another way to **add links to the top navigation menu ?** My problem is, I don't just need to add one link, I need to add multiple links, and they need to be drop-downs.

Comment: have you got solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Create topmenu.phtml in **design/frontend/magento/you_theme/Mageto_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Top menu for store
 *
 * @see \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
 */
?>
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>

<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>
        something...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

2- Refresh cache

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and followed this official Magento tutorial:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html

It gives a good view on how you can achieve what you want.

I ended up with making my own links template to generate a dropdown ([Your_Theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/header/links.phtml):

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links $this*/

enter preformatted text here

if ($this->getLinks()): ?>

<div class="switcher account switcher-account <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCssClass()); ?>" data-ui-id="account-switcher" id="switcher-account">
    <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?php echo __('Account') ?></span></strong>
    <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
        <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger" id="switcher-account-trigger">
            <strong>
                <span><?php echo __('Account') ?></span>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown"
            data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
            "appendTo":"#switcher-account > .options",
            "triggerTarget":"#switcher-account-trigger",
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "triggerClass":"active",
            "parentClass":"active",
            "buttons":null}}'>
            <?php foreach ($this->getLinks() as $link) : ?>
                <?php echo $this->renderLink($link); ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And use it like this (i added this in [Your_Theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml):

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links" template="Magento_Theme::header/links.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Then i moved every existing link into this one:

```
<move element="top.links" destination="header.links"/>
```

Now you can add extra links to that block